# Put Chinese-language entries before English-language entries in the bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing, natbib, sorting

How to put the Chinese papers before English papers on reference list and keep each order unchanged ？

mini example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}

\begin{document}

First citation \cite{eaton2002technology}
Second citation \cite{fanziyin2010}
Third citation \cite{shuangfa}
Fourth citation \cite{Banerjee2012On}

\medskip
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{citation}

\end{document}
```

Bibliography file (`citation.bib`)

```
@article{eaton2002technology,
Author = {Eaton, Jonathan and Kortum, Samuel},
Journal = {Econometrica},
Number = {5},
Pages = {1741--1779},
Publisher = {Wiley Online Library},
Title = {Technology, geography, and trade},
Volume = {70},
presort =  2,
Year = {2002}}


@article{fanziyin2010,
Author = {范子英 and 张军},
Date-Added = {2016-11-05 15:26:38 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2016-11-06 06:10:56 +0000},
Journal = {经济研究},
Number = {3},
Pages = {53--64},
Title = {财政分权, 转移支付与国内市场整合},
Volume = {45},
presort =  1,
Year = {2010}}

@book{shuangfa,
Author = {王晓东},
Date-Added = {2016-11-15 03:23:53 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2016-11-15 12:34:28 +0000},
Publisher = {电子工业出版社},
Title = {计算机算法设计与分析},
   presort = 1,
Year = {2001}}

@inproceedings{Banerjee2012On,
Author = {Banerjee, Abhijit},
Date-Added = {2016-11-12 15:09:14 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2016-11-12 15:09:14 +0000},
Pages = {1--53},
Title = {On the Road: Access to Transportation Infrastructure and Economic Growth in China},
   presort =  2,
Year = {2012}}
```

IDE:Texpad 1.731

Engine: Xelatex, BibTex

Compiled output of the mini example:

[image]

Desired output:
[image]

Comment: Off-topic: In the title field of the Banerjee2012On entry, you should encase the word "China" in curly braces. That way, it won't get lowercased (i.e., typeset as "china") if you use a bibliography style that applies sentence style to the contents of `title` fields.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the `\noopsort` device to place the Chinese-language entries ahead of the remaining entries. The macro `\noopsort` takes 1 argument and is defined as follows:

```
\newcommand{\noopsort}[1]{}
```

For instance, one might amend an `author` field as follows:

```
Author = {{\noopsort{AAA01}}王晓东},
```

At first blush, it very much looks like this macro does absolutely nothing with its argument, other than to gobble it up. :-) This is indeed the case -- *as far as LaTeX is concerned*. However, if `\noopsort` is used inside fields of a bib entry, *BibTeX does not ignore it*. Indeed, for sorting purpose, BibTeX will rewrite the contents of the author field as follows:

```
Author = {AAA01王晓东},
```

Now, because according to the ASCII table "AAA01" comes before names that use the characters of the Latin alphabet, BibTeX will *sort* this entry as coming before the others.

---

[image]

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{citation.bib}

@preamble{ "\providecommand{\noopsort}[1]{} " }

@article{eaton2002technology,
    Author = {Eaton, Jonathan and Kortum, Samuel},
    Journal = {Econometrica},
    Number = {5},
    Pages = {1741--1779},
    Publisher = {Wiley Online Library},
    Title = {Technology, geography, and trade},
    Volume = {70},
    presort =  2,
    Year = {2002}}
@article{fanziyin2010,
    Author = {{\noopsort{AAA02}}范子英 and 张军},
    Date-Added = {2016-11-05 15:26:38 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2016-11-06 06:10:56 +0000},
    Journal = {经济研究},
    Number = {3},
    Pages = {53--64},
    Title = {财政分权, 转移支付与国内市场整合},
    Volume = {45},
    presort =  1,
    Year = {2010}}
@book{shuangfa,
    Author = {{\noopsort{AAA01}}王晓东},
    Date-Added = {2016-11-15 03:23:53 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2016-11-15 12:34:28 +0000},
    Publisher = {电子工业出版社},
    Title = {计算机算法设计与分析},
    presort = 1,
    Year = {2001}}
@inproceedings{Banerjee2012On,
    Author = {Banerjee, Abhijit},
    Date-Added = {2016-11-12 15:09:14 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2016-11-12 15:09:14 +0000},
    Pages = {1--53},
    Title = {On the Road: Access to Transportation Infrastructure and Economic Growth in {China}},
    presort =  2,
    Year = {2012}}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document}
\cite{eaton2002technology}; \cite{fanziyin2010}; \cite{shuangfa}; \cite{Banerjee2012On}.
\bibliography{citation}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up question: If you need to use `kluwer` instead of `\plainnat`, you need to make the following adjustments (in addition to changing the argument of `\bibliographystyle`):

- Provide the instruction `\usepackage{har2nat}` in the preamble. The `kluwer` bibliography style is part of the `harvard` bundle. As such, it is happiest if it's used together with the `harvard` package. If you'd rather keep using `natbib` -- say, because you use `hyperref` and like the ability to create hyperlinks from the citation call-outs to the formatted references -- you should load `har2nat`, which "translates" many (but not all) `harvard` directives into equivalent `natbib` directives.
- Delete the instruction `@preamble{ "\providecommand{\noopsort}[1]{} " }` from the bib file and, instead, insert the instruction `\providecommand{\noopsort}[1]{}` in the preamble of your document.

After making these changes, delete all aux files and run through an entire latex-bibtex-latex-latex compile cycle to fully propagate all changes. You should be getting something like this:

[image]

Comment: A note about the ordering of the two Chinese-language bib entries: I chose `AAA01` and `AAA02` as the noopsort labels based purely on the ordering that was provided in the OP's screenshot. Im afraid I have no knowledge of either how Chinese characters should be sorted or how BibTeX may or may not perform sorting of Chinese characters. Maybe somebody else will post a separate answer on this topic?

Comment: I have to change \bibliographystyle{plainnat}  into \bibliographystyle{kluwer}. Can I use this code @Mico

Comment: @XJ.C - There's a minimal change that has to be made if you need to use the `kluwer` style. I'll post an addendum with the details.