# Rearrange references in the bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biblatex-chicago

I need help with rearranging exactly one pair of references in my bibliography. :)

Currently, my bibliography is arranged alphabetically, which is the right format.
Some author published a correction of a published paper at the same year and my supervisor asked me to rearrange the two citations. So the first published paper should have the index a.

See the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@article{Williamson.1968,
 author = {Williamson, Oliver E.},
 year = {1968},
 title = {Economies as an Antitrust Defense: The Welfare Tradeoffs},
}
@article{Williamson.1968b,
 author = {Williamson, Oliver E.},
 year = {1968},
 title = {Economies as an Antitrust Defense: Correction and Reply},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[authordate,strict,backend=biber,bibencoding=inputenc]{biblatex-chicago} 
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}
This is the first citation \parencite{Williamson.1968}.\\
In the same year, a correction was published \parencite{Williamson.1968b}.

\vspace{5 cm}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Thank you very much!
Best regards!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `sorttitle = {Economies as an Antitrust Defense}` in the first publication.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
 @article{Williamson.1968,
  author = {Williamson, Oliver E.},
  year = {1968},
  title = {Economies as an Antitrust Defense: The Welfare Tradeoffs},
  sorttitle = {Economies as an Antitrust Defense},
 }
 @article{Williamson.1968b,
  author = {Williamson, Oliver E.},
  year = {1968},
  title = {Economies as an Antitrust Defense: Correction and Reply},
 }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[authordate,strict,backend=biber,bibencoding=inputenc]{biblatex-chicago} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
 This is the first citation \parencite{Williamson.1968}.\\
 In the same year, a correction was published \parencite{Williamson.1968b}.
 
 \vspace{5 cm}
 \printbibliography
 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the `\noopsort` trick that works with both bibtex and biber. The macro is defined as

```
\providecommand\noopsort[1]{}
```

This seems like a trivial command, which takes one argument and outputs nothing via LaTeX. But it's not useless, as it can be used to influence how bibtex and biber *sort* entries. In the code below, observe the `\noopsort{a}` and `\noopsort{b}` instructions at the start of the entries' respective `title` fields. Since the `biblatex-chicago` style sorts entries by the `author`, `year`, and `title` fields, the `\noopsort` directives let you achieve your formatting goal.

The `\noopsort` trick is very versatile and has many possible uses. See, for instance, [Put Chinese-language entries before English-language entries in the bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/343307/5001) for an example of how to use `\noopsort` to place, you guessed it, all Chinese-language entries before the other entries in the bibliography.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\providecommand\noopsort[1]{}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{bib.bib}
@article{Williamson.1968a,
 author = {Williamson, Oliver E.},
 year = {1968},
 title = {\noopsort{a}Economies as an Antitrust Defense: The Welfare Tradeoffs},
}
@article{Williamson.1968b,
 author = {Williamson, Oliver E.},
 year = {1968},
 title = {\noopsort{b}Economies as an Antitrust Defense: Correction and Reply},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[authordate,strict,backend=biber,bibencoding=inputenc]{biblatex-chicago} 
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}
This is the first citation \parencite{Williamson.1968a}.
In the same year, a correction was published \parencite{Williamson.1968b}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```